# Jitterbit : Print http request body

Tags: jitterbit

I have a Jitterbit operation that i am trying to debug and as part of this there is a transformation that takes a flat file structure as input and transforms this to a json structure.

This json structure is the input to Http Post operation. I want to print the Http request json body before it executes the request to understand what kind of data is going.

Please suggest a way to get the http body.

[image]

I have tried printing the body to operation log using

```
WriteToOperationLog("Request Body: "+ $jitterbit.api.request.body);
```

and

```
WriteToOperationLog("Request Body: "+ $jitterbit.target.http.b);
```

but it is not printing the http request body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$jitterbit.api.request.body captures the body of an API request sent TO your operation, not what you would be sending outbound. I would suggest two things:

1. If you only care about the body, have the transformation feed into a global variable target, then use a script to write the global variable to your operation log.
2. If you need to capture the full request (i.e., headers and all), [Pipedream](https://pipedream.com/) works well.

Comment: The 1st option worked for me.